# Handling back request properly for an app to work as far back as SDK 4 (API Level 1.6)

Tags: android, android-activity

I've noticed that the 'back' request used to be made at the point a user pressed *down* on the 'back' key but at some point this was changed so that a 'back' request is made instead at the point the 'back' key is released. (Correct me if I am wrong!) Does anyone know from which SDK (or API Level) exactly this change was made effective? I think it was SDK 2.0 (API Level 5) and hence have the code in my Activity as follows but would like to be certain...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
 {
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
   handleBackRequest();

  return true;
 }

 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);        
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
 {
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
   handleBackRequest();

  return true;
 }

 return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code in my previous post I was getting some unwanted behaviour (when dialogs, the android keyboard etc were showing up) and on CommonsWare's advice, changed my code to the following and it seems to be working alright for the different SDKs...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
     && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
 {
  onBackPressed();
  return true;
 }

 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);        
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 // handle back request here
}
```

... Let me know please if there's anything here not quite right!

Answer (score 1):

Use `onBackPressed()` for Android 2.0 and higher. Use `onKeyDown()` for Android 1.6.

Comment: Is handling the 'back' request in the `onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent)` method for _later_ versions of Android not the same as handling it in the `onBackPressed()` method? And so is it 2.0 upwards that I need to treat different?

Comment: @AdilHussain: AFAIK, `onKeyUp()` was never appropriate for the BACK button.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Isn't the default implementation of `onKeyUp(int, KeyEvent)` (when the 'back' key is released; in the latest versions of the Android sdk) simply to call the `onBackPressed()` method such that it is at this point (i.e. when the 'back' key is released) that the 'back' request is made?

Comment: @AdilHussain: Possibly -- I haven't looked. I am simply telling you what Google has told us to do. Google has told us to use `onBackPressed()` for Android 2.0 and higher and use `onKeyDown()` for Android 1.6 and lower. That is what Google will support. Google may or may not support your planned use of `onKeyUp()`.

Comment: Cool. Will give this a try tomorrow and let you know how I get on. Thanks.